# How to iterate over a dictionary's values and add these as rows to a corresponding dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary that stores a user's ID as a key and the events he's performed as a list of tuples. Each tuple contains the date the event was performed and the event itself.

Here is an excerpt from the dictionary:

```
{
 '56d306892fcf7d8a0563b488bbe72b0df1c42f8b62edf18f68a180eab2ca7dc5': 
  [('2018-10-24T08:30:12.761Z', 'booking_initialized')],
 'ac3406118670ef98ee2e3e76ab0f21edccba7b41fa6e4960eea10d2a4d234845': 
  [('2018-10-20T14:12:35.088Z', 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T14:17:38.521Z', 
 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T14:16:41.968Z', 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10- 
 20T13:39:36.064Z', 'search_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T13:47:03.086Z', 
 'visited_hotel')], 
 '19813b0b79ec87975e42e02ff34724dd960c7b05efec71477ec66fb04b6bed9c': [('2018- 
 10-10T18:10:10.242Z', 'referal_code_shared')]
}
```

I also have a dataframe with the corresponding columns:

```
Columns: [visited_hotel, search_hotel, booking_initialized, creferal_code_shared]
```

What I wanted to do was iterate over each dictionary entry and then appropriately append it as row to my dataframe. Each row is a number indicating the number of times the user has performed that event.

So, for example after reading through my dictionary excerpt, my dataframe would read like:

```
  visited_hotel search_hotel booking_initialized referal_code_shared
0     0             0             1                    0

1     4             1             0                    0

2     0             0             0                    1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So are there identical keys in the dictionary? I don't think you want to store them in a dictionary if that is the case.

Comment: Do you mean the IDs? If so, oh no, each id/key in the dictionary is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# d is your dictionary of values

result = {user: Counter(x[1] for x in records)
          for user, records in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(result).fillna(0).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

A slightly cleaner approach

```
result = {i: Counter(x[1] for x in records)
          for i, records in enumerate(d.values()) }

df = pd.DataFrame(result).fillna(0).T
```

If you want your columns in the specific order, then

```
cols = ['visited_hotel', 'search_hotel', 'booking_initialized', 'referal_code_shared']
df = df.loc[:, cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
    '56d306892fcf7d8a0563b488bbe72b0df1c42f8b62edf18f68a180eab2ca7dc5': [('2018-10-24T08:30:12.761Z', 'booking_initialized')],
    'ac3406118670ef98ee2e3e76ab0f21edccba7b41fa6e4960eea10d2a4d234845': [('2018-10-20T14:12:35.088Z', 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T14:17:38.521Z', 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T14:16:41.968Z', 'visited_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T13:39:36.064Z', 'search_hotel'), ('2018-10-20T13:47:03.086Z', 'visited_hotel')],
    '19813b0b79ec87975e42e02ff34724dd960c7b05efec71477ec66fb04b6bed9c': [('2018-10-10T18:10:10.242Z', 'referal_code_shared')]
}

def user_actions(user, actions):
    # Convert the actions to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(actions).rename(columns={0: 'timestamp', 1: 'action'})
    # Count each action
    counted = df.groupby(['action'])['timestamp'].agg('count').reset_index().rename(columns={'timestamp': 'counter'})
    # Pivot the result so each action is a column
    pivoted = counted.pivot(columns='action', values='counter')
    return pivoted

# Process each user's actions and concatenate all
all_actions_df = pd.concat([user_actions(user, user_actions_list) for user, user_actions_list in d.items()]).replace(np.nan, 0)
```

**Output**

```
    booking_initialized referal_code_shared search_hotel    visited_hotel
0   1.0                 0.0                 0.0                 0.0
0   0.0                 0.0                 1.0                 0.0
1   0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 4.0
0   0.0                 1.0                 0.0                 0.0
```